# Decorator Pattern for JTextPane/Document editing

Tags: java, swing, decorator, jtextpane

In an applicaion I'm making there's  a document which needs to be edited by a user through a JTextPane and by an object, that writes when it recieves changes. I now want to log only the users writes, so I thought a decorator pattern would be perfect. The object writes with the methods, insertString, remove and replace, but only two of them (insertString and remove) is defined in the [document interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html), where replace only exists in [abstract document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html).

This has made it impossible to figure out how to do it. Is there a good solution to this?

I've tried using a DocumentFilter, but it will apply to both on the inputs unless you constantly turns it on/off whenever the object writes, which I wanna avoid.

I've tried using a document filter, but as it will apply to both inputs I will have to turn on an off

Comment: `replace` in `AbstractDocument` is a convenience method that just calls `insertString` and/or `remove`

Comment: Have you considered a DocumentListener?